# elastic search preference setting Custom Value(Java api)

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I really really need some helps on elastic search usage in java api...

Let's assume I am using java api from ES.
So far, I understand that elastic search can give inconsistent result due to primary and replica's inconsistency issue(deleting doc makes stats difference in overall due to deletion marking instead of delete it).

So what I tried it

searchRequest.preference("_primary_first"). 
This gave me consistent result(since it only uses primary shard!)

Now what I want to try in my toy example is,

1) using preference=Custom (string) value 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-preference

2) if I have 5 nodes, I want to designate which node we want to use based on the queryText.

For instance,

```
'''
if (queryRequest.text().equals("red")) {
   // use 1st node
   searchRequest.preference("??????")
} else if (queryRequest.text().equals("blue")) {
   // use 2nd node
   searchRequest.preference("??????")
} else {
   // use either 3rd~5th node <- but this is not necessary if it is really hard..
   searchRequest.prefernce("???????")
}

'''
```

Q1)
I guess I need to use custom setting "WISELY" to denote which node to use...
can someone give me simple java.api example?

Q2)
This is another one, but is there any way we can load status for each node from searchResponse?(again in java api friendly)

Q3)
Is there any clever way to specify to use 1st Node(or certain Node Id??) with given query text?(instead using hashmap things...)
For instance,

let say I don't know which query text I will receive, but I want to evenly distribute them to each node(among 5!)

But want to stick with the first choice.

if I see very first query text == "red" and I designate this queryRequest to use Node1, then later I also want to use Node1 if I see the query text == "red" again.. Does someone have idea?

Thank you guys!

Disclaimer:
I am non-CS guy and independant learner who tried to experiment new things to break my comfort zones! :) Please excuse this silly question!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not a silly question and the answer has two parts.

You mention nodes and you want to control which node gets what queries based on an attribute.

Some context:

- An elasticsearch cluster has elasticsearch nodes
- Your documents will be "saved" in an elasticsearch index and the queries you perform will be against that index
- An elasticsearch index is but an abstraction, a layer that hides the complexity of shards (basically lucene indices).

Now when you save a document, that document will eventually be stored in a shard (there are segments etc, but no reason to go any further). Now you can have primary shards and replica shards. When you save something, that will go to a primary shard and will be replicated by elasticsearch to the replica shards (if any). Your searches can and will be served both by primary and replica shards.

Now, you want to control which node gets what. What you can control is which shard gets what via [routing on save](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) and via [routing on search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html).

You've asked to control which node get's what. Most of the times you won't be needing this. What you can control is what shard gets what, so you'll need to control which node gets what shard. This can be accomplished via [shard allocation awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-awareness.html).

Both of these topics are advanced features and you'll need to make sure to know what you are doing when trying to use them or you'll get very unexpected results.